# Dylibs and OS X 

Tags: macos, boost, homebrew, dylib, vowpalwabbit

I am trying to run a program called vowpal-wabbit (version 6.0) in mac os x.

I've used homebrew to install some things, such as lib tools and, importantly, boost.

However -- I'm finding that, even though

```
/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.49.0/lib
```

Clearly has all the boost libs, (including lib boost_program_options.dylib)...

The error message i get when trying to run a binary is :

```
dyld: Library not loaded: libboost_program_options.dylib
```

I get the same (basically) error when running "make" to build this binary from scratch :

```
ld: library not found for -lboost_program_options
```

So ... I guess my question is : How can I get my compiled binary to "see" the libboost_program_options.dylib ? Or alternatively... how can I get vw  (version 6.0) running on os x lion.

Answer (score 4):

I'll guess that `/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.49.0/lib` is not on either `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` or `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH`. You could export either of those in your environment, or you could symlink the Boost libraries from `/usr/local/lib`.

Be careful not to wipe out the contents of `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH`, though! From the `dyld` man page, the default value for this is `$(HOME)/lib:/usr/local/lib:/lib:/usr/lib`.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I ADD /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.49.0/lib to the path ?

Comment: Yes, that's right: `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.49.0/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` (assuming you're using bash).