# How to run Shakespeare (.SPL) file in C

Tags: c, compiler-construction, shakespeare-lang

How do I run a program written in Shakespeare Programming Language?  I've scanned the internet for the info but I still can't solve this problem.

On the [original site](http://shakespearelang.sourceforge.net/) it's given a translator for C and some GCC Frontend links. However, the links just don't work and I can't understand an instruction for the translator.

In the point "How To Compile Your SPL Program" it's written

> First, spl2c reads from `stdin` and writes to `stdout`, so to accomplish what you see in the figure, you would write `spl2c < hello.spl > hello.c`. Second, the object file must be linked with the library `libspl.a`, which contains such stuff as dreams are made on.

I can't get it at all.

Comment: An esoteric one. I just need it for my studies and I am interested in it as well.

Comment: Well, it sounds like you're supposed to run `spl2c` which will read your SPL file and generate C code. You then compile the generate C code and link it with libspl. Which of these steps is giving you trouble?

Comment: @Nik Bougalis, sadly, even the first one makes trouble. Firstly, because there is no spl2c file in the archive - [SPL](http://shakespearelang.sourceforge.net/download/spl-1.2.1.tar.gz). Secondly, I'd have no idea how to run it, as it has no commands or descriptions like what it should be opened with.

Comment: I guess the answer lies somewhere [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050362/translating-shakespeare-programming-language). I'd need to execute "Makefile" so that it builds a translator. And then to run spl2c. However, I have no idea how to do this in Windows.

Comment: Install cygwin, or give up on Windows.

Comment: The `spl2c` executable does not exist in the archive, you'll need to build it using the source code provided using a C compiler and GNU Bison.  SPL is written to work on Unix-like operating systems (which means it'll work on Linux, BSDs, Macs, etc).  However, if you *really* want to make it work on Windows, you can probably use Cygwin/MinGW like bmargulies suggested, but it's difficult for someone without the experience.  You'll have an easier time getting it to run on Linux or something.

Answer (score 2):

OK. You can compile the spl2c using MinGW if you don't want to try cygwin.

I set my students writing an SPL(*) compiler as an exercise, to help them I made a your tube video of downloading and using the MinGW software. Its simple enough for most dummies.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=58I6nAybzzI&list=PL3czsVugafjNLmIHA8ODBxuwWy8W4Uk9h&index=2

(*) Actually its a different SPL